# libtool (arm): error: only absolute run-paths are allowed

Tags: path, arm, cross-compilation, libtool

I am cross-compiling SSSD for ARM architecture. 
When I run `make`, I obtain the following error:

```
arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-libtool:   error: only absolute run-paths are allowed
```

I configure it as follows:

```
./configure --host=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi  \
--prefix=/absolute/path/for/installation \
--with-selinux=no \
--with-kcm=no \
--without-python3-bindings \
--without-samba \
--without-nfsv4-idmapd-plugin \
--disable-valgrind-memcheck --disable-valgrind-helgrind --disable-valgrind-drd --disable-valgrind-sgcheck --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-libtool-lock --with-manpages=no  --disable-cifs-idmap-plugin --with-libnl=no
```

After some research, I understood there should be something to adjust in the makefile, but I don't know what to modify. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?